# Is there a way to get the album artwork img src from a discogs.com listing?

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

I am trying to use preg_match or preg_match_all to get the cover art from https://www.discogs.com/Lady-Gaga-Chromatica/release/15386439

So far I've only been able to get the Discogs logo and the favicon.

Here is the code I am using, which yields two images, the logo of Discogs.com and the favicon:

```
<?php
$text = file_get_contents("https://www.discogs.com/Lady-Gaga-Chromatica/release/15386439");
preg_match_all('/<img.*>/',$text,$out);
print_r($out);
?>
```

Edit 1:
I was asked to copy the data I'm trying to collect the image from, this is a lot of data so I am not able to post it here. It would be best if you could look at https://www.discogs.com/Lady-Gaga-Chromatica/release/15386439 and isnpect source to see the data.

Edit 2:
I looked at the console and see a 400 Bad Request code. But if I print out $text from the previous code, I can get the whole page to load on my webpage so I don't get why I can't fetch just the images.

Comment: Please include the data from which you are trying to extract image tags.

Comment: The data is 158'000 characters, and the limit is 30'000 so I'm sorry but I can't post the whole site. I can only advise you to go to the website linked and inspect source.